# ¿Como puedo cambiar el tamaño de la consola en C al iniciar un programa?

Tags: c

Estoy buscando un modo que predetermine el tamaño de la consola al iniciar el programa.
La idea es que al abrir la aplicación, esta abra una nueva consola con el tamaño elegido por mí.
Con la siguiente imagen creo que se comprenderá a la perfección.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su ayuda!

Comment: Es en inglés, pero puede ayudarle https://www.programming-techniques.com/2011/09/how-to-resize-console-window-using-c.html

Comment: Si reseñaras el código en el enlace y comentaras brevemente qué hacer con él, sería una respuesta perfectamente válida, @Duston :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para definir el tamaño de nuestra consola declararemos las siguientes líneas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
HANDLE wHnd;

int main (){
    
    
    wHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SMALL_RECT windowSize = {0, 0, 30, 15};
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(wHnd, 1, &windowSize);
    return 0;
}
```

Modificando los valores del array windowSize obtendremos las proporciones deseadas.
El tercer valor '30' es el ancho y '15' la altura.

El resultado:

[image: Imagen resultado]

Gracias Duston por tu comentario!